# Trying to find the correct code for either a nested formula or a stacked formula and not able to get it

Tags: excel-formula

If once cell D2 has value of 2, multiply that value times another cell C2=$480, but if D2 is blank, check another cell for value E2, if it has value E2=3, multiply that value times cell C2=$480

> IF D2="","",D2 * C2; if D2 is blank, look in E2 and if E2="","",E2 X C2; stacked or nested

Answer (score 2):

Nest two IFs

```
=IF(D2<>"",D2 * C2,IF(E2<>"",E2* C2,""))
```

Comment: If neither are true, it shows "FALSE", and I want it to remain blank.  Any way to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

Use an IFS statement (notice, it's just IF but an 'S' on the end).

`IFS(D2=2, C2*D2, E2=3, C2*E2, TRUE, "Neither true")`

In the above example, we check if D2=2 and if it does multiply C2*D2. Otherwise, check if E2=3 and if it does multiply C2*E2. Otherwise, display "neither true":

**IF vs IFS:**

- IF takes one true/false statement and gives you a result IF true, or a different result IF false. `IF(true/false, true_result, false_result)`
- IFS checks one true/false statement, and if true does the following command. Otherwise, checks the next statement for true/false and if true does the following command. Ad infinitum. `IF(true/false_1, true_result_1, true/false_2, true_result_2, ...)`

Comment: Note that `IFS` is not available in all versions of Excel.

Comment: My version does not support IFS, but that solution would be great, LOL